# Reloading Samba4's smb.conf without restarting the service

Tags: configuration, samba4

I want to tweak smb.conf without causing network hiccups for folks who rely on our samba4 fileshare.

I made an obvious path change that should only affect my own private share, and ran `smbcontrol smbd reload-config`.  It didn't complain, but didn't affect my share, either.  I also tried `smbcontrol samba4 reload-config`, which returned `Can't find pid for destination 'samba4'`, so I tried without the '4', and it had the same no-change behaviour as `smbd`.

Is there a way to reload the conf in Samba 4 without closing open files and the like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try with sending SIGHUP signal to `smbd` process

```
killall -HUP smbd nmbd
```

NOTE:   Be careful using killall on Unix. Running killall on Solaris on root would send kill signals to all processes! [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall]

Comment: smbd isn't used on samba4

Comment: and this would restart the service and boot everyone, wouldn't it?

Comment: Signal HUP only will reload configuration,not fully stop and start. to enable at boot, you need to use `update-rc.d servicename defaults`. and yes in samba4 service name is `/usr/local/samba/sbin/samba`, if you are using compiled version then you can use init script from this link > https://github.com/rahulinux/samba4

Comment: Be careful using `killall` on Unix. Running `killall` on Solaris on root would send kill signals to *all* processes! [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Killall]

Comment: @donothingsuccessfully thanks.. updated..

Comment: `smbd` is used on Samba 4.1 on Debian Jessie. Maybe that is distribution dependent.

Answer (score 27):

Use this: `smbcontrol all reload-config`

Force daemon to reload smb.conf configuration file. Can be sent to smbd, nmbd, or winbindd. The all destination causes the message to "broadcast" to all running daemons including nmbd and winbind.

Comment: Good, but more detailed answers are better.

Comment: sorry, I have bad english :)

Comment: I think peterh means: Why is "all" the answer?  Which component is needed besides smbd or samba4?  (Then we can target it instead of restarting all services, which may not be desirable.)

Comment: the command show "reload" not restart... Needs eyeglasses :D

You can use it as you like all, smbd a nmbd or a winbindd.read the samba documentation in the find the examples

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smbcontrol.1.html